# QGIS: Editing .qml files

Tags: qgis, qml

I tried to follow [these](https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/) intructions on creating google-styled maps from osm-data. I have the SpatialLite data in QGIS (2.18) and now tried to load the styles provided by Anita. I open the properties window of each layer, click on "style" -> "load style" -> "load from file" and select the respective style. Irrespectively of the layer and style I choose, I get this error:

> unexpected character at line 35 column 91

I don't get this error when using other stylesheets. Nevertheless, I'd like to use Anitas styles, so I hope it is possible to figure out how to change her files in a way that make them usable with QGIS 2.18. However, I do not know how to edit these files.

Can anyone suggest a sensible starting point?

Comment: I "fixed" it by downloading the complete collection of anitas data - the files in this directory work well.

Comment: Most probably you did not download from the `Raw` button on Github. Therefore you got a html file, not the raw style file.

Comment: Thank you for this comment - it's good to get such hints when one is very new to all of this.